# How to edit .htaccess file to remove string at the end

Tags: file, .htaccess

I have links to my site from other sites that have ?id=- in them, and I think it was from a plugin that I had. I have removed the plugin because it didn't work. Now all those links to my site are coming up as a 404. So, I want to fix those so that they keep coming to my site.

Here are some examples of the links coming to my site:

/marketing-your-business?id=-    Should go to: /marketing-your-business

/small-business-tips?id=-  should go to: /small-business-tips

You get the idea.

I have no idea what to put in my .htaccess file to fix these urls before they get a 404 error page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=-
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R]
```